# Amazon EC2: Security Group not respecting my custom inbound and outbound rules

Tags: amazon-ec2

so I limited my inbound and outbound in my security group policy to my ip only, however, I find that I can access it from any other IP address. does the ec2 instance need to be restarted in order to reflect the new security group policy?

Comment: Are you sure you added your (presumably home?  office?) IP correctly?  Are there network ACLs for the subnet that may override your security group rule?  Please post AWS console screenshots or AWS CLI output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No instance need **not** be restarted for applying security policy.

You need to check if there are multiple security-group's attached to instance.

Comment: it's not true, changes are applied immediatly

Comment: that is what I said !  One doesn't have to restart.

Comment: Why down votes, I said the same the same, instance doesn't have to restart ?